# Powershell: Can I change the Color in a richTextBox with an click event?

Tags: powershell

I am looking to change the background color of a richTextBox when a user clicks on it. I figure I will need a click event. the colors should be specific, so they don't make the text hard to read. I figure I will need a list or array to choose the colors from. I don't think I will need a random function but just a way to change the richTextBox color. any Ideas?

Thanks

```
 #Generated Form Function
function GenerateForm {
#######################################################################
# Generated On: 8/30/2016 4:54 PM
# Generated By: christnerw
########################################################################

#region Import the Assemblies
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
#endregion

#region Generated Form Objects
$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$richTextBox4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$richTextBox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$richTextBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$richTextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState
#endregion Generated Form Objects

#region Generated Form Code
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 262
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 284
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$form1.Name = "form1"
$form1.Text = "Primal Form"

$richTextBox4.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 140
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 150
$richTextBox4.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox4.Name = "richTextBox4"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 100
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 100
$richTextBox4.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox4.TabIndex = 3
$richTextBox4.Text = ""

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox4)

$richTextBox3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 32
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 150
$richTextBox3.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox3.Name = "richTextBox3"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 100
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 100
$richTextBox3.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox3.TabIndex = 2
$richTextBox3.Text = ""

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox3)

$richTextBox2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 32
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 37
$richTextBox2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox2.Name = "richTextBox2"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 98
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 100
$richTextBox2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox2.TabIndex = 1
$richTextBox2.Text = ""

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox2)

$richTextBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 140
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 37
$richTextBox1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 98
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 100
$richTextBox1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox1.TabIndex = 0
$richTextBox1.Text = ""

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox1)

#endregion Generated Form Code

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
#Show the Form
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

} #End Function

#Call the Function
GenerateForm
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a Hashtable to store your color pairs (back/fore), and then execute the color change on the GotFocus and LostFocus event.

```
$Colors = @{
    'Black'='White'
    'White'='Black'
}
Function ColorSwap = {
Param([string]$Ctrl)
    Invoke-Expression ('${0}.BackColor = $Colors.(${0}.BackColor)' -f $Ctrl)
    Invoke-Expression ('${0}.ForeColor = $Colors.(${0}.ForeColor)' -f $Ctrl)
}
$richTextBox1.add_GotFocus({ColorSwap richTextBox1})
$richTextBox1.add_LostFocus({ColorSwap richTextBox1})
$richTextBox2.add_GotFocus({ColorSwap richTextBox2})
$richTextBox2.add_LostFocus({ColorSwap richTextBox2})
$richTextBox3.add_GotFocus({ColorSwap richTextBox3})
$richTextBox3.add_LostFocus({ColorSwap richTextBox3})
$richTextBox4.add_GotFocus({ColorSwap richTextBox4})
$richTextBox4.add_LostFocus({ColorSwap richTextBox4})
```

That *should* make it so when you click in the box it sets the background to black and font to white, and swaps it back when you click outside the box. You could add color pairs to the hashtable if desired.